# How to access .bat file content through C# .Net?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a .bat file with content Older version and New version. I want to access that version values through C# .Net(VS2005). How can I access?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into memory and parse the content.

[`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) will return the contents of the specified file.

As you didn't specify what the batch file looks like, there isn't any more to say...